# Disable two finger tap zoom out on MKMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I'm trying to disable the zoom out functionality on two finger (single) tap on a MKMapView.  I've added a gesture recogniser, but the selector does not get called.  The idea was this would override the default one and stop the zoom out.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* twoFingerTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doStuff:)];
[twoFingerTapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
[twoFingerTapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTapRecognizer];
```

My `doStuff` method is not called (and the zoom out occurs).  However if I change `setNumberOfTapsRequired` to `2` then `doStuff` is called (and the zoom out still occurs).

```
[self.mapView gestureRecognizers];
```

The above only lists my other recognisers (some single tap recognisers).

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: add that code how to disable zoom functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking?  I'm not trying to disable zoom functionality, just the two finger, single tap, which zooms out.  Pinching and single tap should still zoom.